# Find a string and only print the required keyword

Tags: parsing, batch-file, cmd

```
05-08 23:38:08.484 11404 11764 I Ads     : GMA Debug CONTENT {"timestamp":1588961288491,"event":"onNetworkRequest","components":["network_request_36385a69-b99e-4da6-b6a0-7bf2a106a285"],"params":{"firstline":{"uri":"https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?submodel=SM-N915G&android_app_volume=1&disable_ml=false&format=interstitial_mb&omid_v=a.1.3.1-google_20200121&is_nonagon=true&android_app_muted=false&am=0&dv=21400&gl=GB&hl=en&js=afma-sdk-a-v201004999.14300000.1&lv=0&ms=CoACClZSVfMXCRQ-WNImS5Q9B8Kr7uHr8m5cVL4sU3c951ZafOWUx64ymtfyXUpdXg0A95gRozZwS4W6-w_RmoEeWxq56UkgzPcVmiNEL1Aa8-v6Cik5s15gGkF5AHJpfjwSOynwJ7ZEgj78CEI_AvDrK8pfF4OhctAnxYwxMmeZDX4zqP8dLptQ8EIZtjfmEtXjFS3lzvdrHUpgsG8E_EscYo0xlLZu7zzQe8GpDRUhnkQr4xGv4ou4ZqbLmstqeZdPLcZX1xROBq_rLfY_3cY7z8Tf8seqVNsTI49EG2HZuMjCLRFOmtinp3mFO8du9pxSg4cNV2JxjxFox1TGQ2QLqQqAAjorBHB9GJsXM85JwwKB2h9tQAvgPoaJZRwBhJQHB_qs2iswjcSsJldAYHKe105wq7VihcvZVM7oLDfQhQqWuQFYb27LCf9UH43etMBZvMq7aAOpKj5ilbFHdg13wiFIdsNlQ1Kv6saMKKSi4WPoScw1bW9WEqPrSuLZDwo6NN4iFo1cJ_2dD5Xu4R52ytmY70NkOeTVa07KGAVwR0GARwuRX6VTKtDAsWap6OybQAF9ZtCwbs5h8Man9xrlaxJRuuzzhH1KEnp3Nld-8JfXglPI4-8yOXRWjnB3fQadPz2BLEKiq-pUtZVrrRqIeQu5jDMjX69Oks3XSHwECN6D32ASENSnE_R_crSMn7XDhwnuK-4&mv=81983300.com.android.vending&rm=2&sp=false&coh=true&riv=11&u_sd=2.4&request_id=4145396e-4ada-4bd7-854a-11556ade0f70&render_in_browser=false&target_api=29&carrier=40407&is_sidewinder=false&seq_num=1&eid=318482080%2C318490406%2C318484496%2C318486317%2C318484676%2C318482960%2C318482459%2C318483611%2C318486978%2C318487060%2C318489974%2C318475417%2C318483742&tag_for_child_directed_treatment=0&_c_csdk_npa_o=false&_c_req_npa=false&npa=0&guci=0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0&rbv=1&u_w=640&u_h=383&msid=com.ea.gp.nbamobile&_package_name=com.ea.gp.nbamobile&an=44310.android.com.ea.gp.nbamobile&net=wi&u_audio=3&u_so=l&preqs_in_session=2&support_transparent_background=true&preqs=0&time_in_session=310380&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=330&url=44310.android.com.ea.gp.nbamobile.adsenseformobileapps.com&gdfp_req=1&markup=html&m_ast=afmajs&impl=ifr&iu=%2F220%2FNBALive%2FAndroid%2FRewarded_Video%2FDashboard&sz=480x320&oct_ist=1&correlator=1486806085148500&gsb=wi&lite=true&vfmt=18&vst=0&sdkv=o.201004999.14300000.1&sdki=3c4d&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_mraid3_sdkVideo_exo3_th_autoplay_mediation_scroll_av_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di_sfv_dinm_dim_nav_navc_dinmo_ipdof_gls_gcache_xSeconds&bisch=true&blev=0.86&swdr=false&cans=5&canm=false&_mv=23.android&heap_free=9792968&heap_max=268435456&heap_total=38043632&wv_count=0&rdps=15650&blockAutoClicks=true&cust_params=excl_cat%26optout%3Dno%26coppa%3Dno&rewarded_version=1&includeDoritos=true&rdidl=36&idtypel=4&is_latl=-1&blob=ABPQqLGrcFoEjqzU1D-terFskdukGTLEuTUawcm0pBN0aB1d8YNSg6mLc5H5hWfITabn9X_sTUR-xainyvLxhx-QMpVlfZXee0FH8Z8Fjs6uM7kH5i5_Ej4OWZHYmzzc27g9uusoPfNAP_WRsabkoO4MOzGcL_wF_NLF8S72uFyd1TxihwAptei3UGc8midRCER_2m49ZCG92iIMZnSTLY3GHkm3yeGBDjP16FauKMJMYYX2n1MfK52OyblTrPquFX6adhiTApYLs-oIRLLuzbInS3P5cscrCxfBIHIkxOrqtg_fXXJTkgjUzk8Nhp3Tnm-4lN0lNRyzNnic-TU&et=125&tcar=194&jsv=sdk_20190107_RC02-canary-production-sdk_20200428_RC00&urll=2888#caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_mraid2_mraid3_sdkVideo_exo3_th_autoplay_mediation_scroll_av_transparentBackground_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di_sfv_dinm_dim_nav_navc_dinmo_ipdof_gls_gcache_xSeconds&eid=318482080%252C318490406%252C318484496%252C318486317%252C318484676%252C318482960%252C318482459%252C318483611%252C318486978%252C318487060%252C318489974%252C318475417%252C318483742&format=interstitial_mb&heap_free=9792968&heap_max=268435456&heap_total=38043632&js=afma-sdk-a-v201004999.14300000.1&msid=com.ea.gp.nbamobile&preqs=0&seq_num=1&target_api=29","verb":"GET"},"headers":[{"name":"User-Agent","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-N915G Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Mobile Safari/537.36 (Mobile; afma-sdk-a-v201004999.14300000.1)"},{"name":"Cookie","value":"IDE=AHWqTUlALo2Mq3Qp52ZNNvAhzeqdzEJ0K5nNOV3OKMFW3vapCmqRNqnN6tIrx26A"}]}}
```

From this I want the output to be printed as:
`tag_for_child_directed_treatment=0`, if I enter `tag_for_child_directed_treatment` in the input or else its fine if it prints complete string `tag_for_child_directed_treatment=0`

I have tried with the code:

```
@echo off

set /P search_string= Enter the string you would like to search for:
find "%search_string%" C:\Users\Bhargav\logcat1.txt

pause
```

It gives the output as a complete line, can anyone help me?

Comment: `find.exe` and `findstr.exe` both return lines which contain the string match. You therefore cannot use them alone, to return a substring from a matched line. What you'd need to do is to somehow split the line up, or perferably use another scripting language or utility.

Comment: @Compo: in other words: `findstr` tries to be a Windows replacement for `grep`, but some features (like `grep -o`, for only showing the matched result) are not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Get the string.
Cut it from the beginning to (including) the search-string.
extract the number.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "search_string=tag_for_child_directed_treatment"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do set "string=%%a"
set "string=!string:*%search_string%=!"
for /f "delims==&" %%a in ("!string!") do set "result=%%a"
echo %search_string%=%result%
```

**EDIT** (slightly adapted to take care of multiple entries in the text file):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "search_string=tag_for_child_directed_treatment"
for /f "delims=" %%t in (test.txt) do ( 
  set "string=%%t"
  set "string=!string:*%search_string%=!"
  for /f "delims==&" %%a in ("!string!") do echo result=%%a
)
```

Batch is horrible to process such a string. A more reliable solution is possible with [dbenham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012053)'s utility [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044), a hybrid JScript/batch script with full REGEX support, which makes this task quite easy:

```
@echo off
set "search_string=tag_for_child_directed_treatment"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.txt ^| jrepl ".*tag_for_child_directed_treatment=([0-9]*).*" "$1" /XSEQ') do set "result=%%a"
echo %search_string%=%result%
```

**EDIT** (slightly adapted to take care of multiple entries in the text file):

```
@echo off
set "search_string=tag_for_child_directed_treatment"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.txt ^| jrepl ".*tag_for_child_directed_treatment=([0-9]*).*" "$1" /XSEQ') do echo result=%%a
```

Comment: hey i have tried the 1st one and the output is :
tag_for_child_directed_treatment=05-08 23:55:15.894 11404 13177 I Ads     : GMA Debug FINISH

where after tag_for_child_directed_treatment=0 this i dont want those values

Comment: both codes give output `tag_for_child_directed_treatment=0` with `test.txt` containing the string copied from your question.

Comment: Hey i have ran it and the output observed is tag_for_child_directed_treatment=04-16 22:23:32.004  5896 26663 D WifiConnectivityMonitor.DnsPingerHandler: setCurrentLinkProperties: lp
Press any key to continue . . .

i just need the search string output as 0 or 1 and also i had a log of multiple urls with the search string it needs to print the output of the search string until it goes through the eof

Comment: example of log: -2KbJCwBYSDtmOSDlTh3FZoAW3jLeLTJ-8sK-XlYAfQHa1uo5SsKNbbx5fvcQj25OXRswSEKWMjLwr3V0xaatxmsogcFg&mv=81971200.com.android.vending&rm=1&sp=false&coh=true&riv=0&u_sd=3.5&request_id=1f17bd18-d404-4cbe-925a-8ccfa33e79e4&render_in_browser=false&target_api=29&carrier=40449&is_sidewinder=false&seq_num=2&eid=318489968%2C318482079%2C318484497%2C318486317%2C318477280%2C318484676%2C318483611%2C318484801%2C318486977%2C318487060%2C318489974%2C318475417&tag_for_child_directed_treatment=0&_c_csdk_npa_o=false&_c_req_npa=false&npa=0&guci=0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0&rbv=1&u_w=813&u_

Comment: my codes give `%result%` as `0`, both from the input in your question and in your above comment. I slightly adapted both codes to take care of several occurrences in the file. If you want just the pure numbers (as requested in your comment) or the complete string (as requested in your question), adapt the `echo` commands accordingly.